# How effective is flea and tick spot treatment on dogs with hair?

Tags: dogs, health, fleas, parasites, ticks

I have an Australian LabraDoodle (lab, poodle, cocker spaniel, english spaniel, water spaniel) with curly hair (as opposed to fur).

It's my understanding that dogs with normal fur produce more oils than dogs with hair, so a spot treatment for parasite prevention spreads correctly. With this in mind, does spot treatment on a dog with hair spread and work as effectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears as though flea and tick treatment is effective on dogs with all hair types, despite the differences in oil production, as long as the product is applied correctly.

From [Bioactivation in Fleas](http://www.bioactivation-in-fleas.co.uk/pages/faq/faq.aspx):

> [Flea and Tick removal] products move through the oily coating of the dog or cat’s hair and skin in exactly the same way in long and short-haired breeds. To provide the best care for your pet, just ensure that you select the correct product size for your dog or cat based on its weight.

Because it is applied directly to the skin instead of the fur itself (which has no effect on the overall effectiveness on the treatment), spot treatment should work on dogs with all hair types.

From [PetMeds.com](http://www.1800petmeds.com/education/flea-medicine-not-working-7.htm) on product application:

> Touch the skin with the applicator tip. Don't put the applicator tip in the hair because hair cannot absorb product. Put the tip on the skin, which is able to absorb the medication. You can slide the applicator under the hair (rather than parting the hair with your fingers) if you are sure the applicator touches the skin. Apply along the back where your pet cannot reach. You can apply to one spot or several spots, however, the more often you lift the applicator tip and move to another location, the more likely you are to get product in the hair or on yourself.

[image]

There is also a helpful article on [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Advantage-to-Dogs) that explains the treatment process.

> Locate the middle of the dog's back at the base of its neck between the shoulder blades. Use one hand to part the fur and expose the skin.  Use a disposable hair clip or hair elastic to hold the fur out of the way if your dog is long-haired or has a thick coat. This will help you get the product on the dog's skin, not the fur.

Comment: From my own experience, I have found that my dog with hair has less oils in her hair than dogs with fur. This means that the medicine doesn't spread as effectively.