# Serious flea problems with my dog

Tags: dogs, medicines, fleas

## History of the problem

I have a lot of problems getting rid of the fleas which torture my dog (A year and a half Yorkie :) ). First a brief history + info on what we have tried and what ware the results.

At first for the first time our dog got fleas after we groomed him (mid summer) before that he didn't had any. Once we groomed him in a few days he started scratching more than usual, after we checked him we saw a few on his back(following the length of the spine), not more than 10 ware spotted and that was it. We showered him with regular dog shampoo, used a "spot on" drops as a prevention measures and the problem seemed to be solved.

After a few days(not more than a week) we noticed that the little guy started scratching again and from time to time to bite his legs, when we examined we saw more than the previous time and we got [flee repellent shampoo](http://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/dog/dog-healthcare/dog-flea-treatment/herbal-dog-flea-shampoo) and spot on drops from a different brand, showered him thoroughly with the shampoo and used the drops again.

On the very next day he was scratching again and had the fleas again. This time we ware in for more serious measures, we got a [spray](http://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/dog/dog-healthcare/dog-flea-treatment/dog-flea-spray-150ml) and the "protective night lamp thingy" so he couldn't lick himself (advised by the instructions and by a staff member from pets at home). It worked for the night and the next day, that was it.

We sprayed him again, but after the result was the same we stopped (the spray is kind of dangerous and we don't want to cause the little fella more trouble)

After we got to the store again and this time we got these [tablets](http://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/johnsons-4fleas-for-puppies-and-small-dogs-6-pack-tablets) and these [drops](http://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/bob-martin-flea-clear-spot-on-solution-1-x-67mg-for-small-dogs-2---10kg?pageSize=83#). We gave him a bath with the same shampoo, gave hime the tablets and they took effect in about 20 minutes and we started seeing the evil creatures on the floor (which was expected result), used the drops and that was it, the effect was for about 10 days.

2 days ago we gave him a bath with the same shampoo and today when I got home I started petting him in his bed, and when he rolled on his back, I saw a very large group of the fleas running on his belly, when I started examining him, I saw that there are large fleas, like they ware there from a long time as well as smaller ones, around his nipples(?) I saw signs of wounds from either scratching or biting by those things.

## Now the question

1. How should we approach the problem now?
2. Can you recommend any other products, which helped you before?

## Side info

We live in East London, UK. A large number of cats are passing trough the back yard(which is our first assumption for the cause of the problem), we treated the garden with animal repellent (to keep all kind of animals away) as well with some garden pest controlling product (It was supposed to kill the fleas(it was written on the label), don't remember any name, got it from the local pet store).

The dog is living in the house with us, no other pets. He goes in the garden when he wants, but mainly for 5-10 minutes and always sleeps inside. We walk him in the area (we avoid dog parks, ever since we spotted fleas on him).

## Note:

I looked at [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/107/how-can-i-get-rid-of-fleas) and [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/effectiveness-of-flea-tick-spot-treatment-on-dogs-with-hair) questions, but they don't seem to cover our situation. (I am considering the idea in the first question: mixing powder with warm water and spray him)

I do apologize, I know that the question is little too localized and might end up closed, but I am kind of desperate right now.

Comment: As I already mentioned, we have treated the garden (and keep doing it) as well as the dog. But the problem persists and it is getting worse. Which is the reason I posted the question here.

Comment: http://www.whole-dog-journal.com/issues/5_3/features/5436-1.html

Comment: I am going to close this as a duplicate. I see that @MattS. put a bounty on the original flea question. Since you have >20 reputation, I would also advise asking in chat to draw attention to the question and specific details of your case. I also recommend that any persistent problem like you are experiencing be taken to your local vet. If the fleas are resistant or if they are another bug, your vet will be able to help you solve those problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to de-flea your house as well and not just your garden area. Going to the vet is a good idea too, especially since the fleas you have might've built up a resistance to the over the counter stuff you've been using.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to consult a vet. I think that the flea treatments that you can get from your vet are stronger than the ones you buy from a store. Be sure to apply them as often as the vet recommends. And talk to the vet about other treatments that you have used (shampoo, yard, etc.) to make sure that there are no contraindications.